# Let $f(x)=0$ for $x\leq 1$ and $f(x)=1$ for $x>1$. Let $F(x)=\int_0^x f$. How do we explain that $F'$ is not defined at $1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Let $F(x)=\int_0^x f$, where

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} 0, \text{ if } x \leq 1 \\ 1, \text{ if } x>1 \end{cases}$$

[image]

**Main questions:** At which points $x$ is $F'(x)=f(x)$, and more importantly, what is the justification? What is the justification for a point not to be such that $F'(x)=f(x)$?

**Below is what I came up with** It is probably prolix and incorrect.

$f$ is continuous on $(-\infty,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$.

**Question 1:** if we consider just the interval $(-\infty, 1]$, can we say $f$ is continuous on this interval? Of course, what I am really asking is if we can actually make the statement solely based on the fact that

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 1^-} f(x)=f(1)=0$$

In any case, $f$ is integrable on $(-\infty, 1]$ Therefore, since we know that $g(x)=c$ is such that $g'(x)=0=f(x)$ for $x\leq 1$, we can apply the second fundamental theorem of calculus (FTC2) to conclude that for $x\leq1$ we have $F(x)=0$.

Similarly, $f$ is continuous and thus integrable on the interval $(1,\infty)$. Furthermore, since a single point doesn't change the integrability of a function or the value of an integral, we know that $f$ is integrable on $[1,\infty)$.

Let $h(x)=x$. Then $h'(x)=f(x)$ for $x \in (1,\infty)$.

**Question 2:** I would think to apply FTC2 to the open interval $(1,\infty)$. The FTC2 is stated in terms of a closed interval, however. I am not sure if I can actually apply FTC2 to $(1,\infty)$. Can I?

If we apply the FTC2 to $f$ on $(1,\infty)$ we obtain

$$F(x)=\int\limits_0^1 f + \int\limits_1^x f$$

$$=0+x-1$$

$$=x-1$$

Thus

$$F(x)=\begin{cases} 0, \text{ if } x \leq 1 \\ x-1, \text{ if } x > 1 \end{cases}$$

and $F'(x)$ is undefined at $x=1$ because the right- and left-hand derivatives are different.

[image]

Comment: This discussion looks more-or-less correct. (There's a typo in Question 1 where you write $[\infty, 1]$, which is not a valid interval.)

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is ok, but why not do it from scratch? That is, observe that, for $h>0,$

$\displaystyle\frac{F(1+h)-F(1)}{h}=\frac{1}{h}\int_1^{1+h} f(t)dt=1$

whereas

$\displaystyle\frac{F(1-h)-F(1)}{h}=-\frac{1}{h}\int_{1-h}^1 f(t)dt=0$

so the right and left-hand limits in the definition of derivative are different.

Comment: Is it not necessary to check the value of $F$ at the other points in its domain so we can make sure there aren't any other points like $1$? I think this is why I made a longer argument.

Comment: All you care about is the (non-)existence of the derivative at $x=1.$ It's a local property. Or am I misreading your question?

Comment: This problem is actually from Spivak's Calculus.

From drawing the graph of $f$ it is pretty obvious where $F'(x)$ probably won't be differentiable. 

However, the main question the problem poses is at which points $x$ is $F'(x)=f(x)$. The point of the problem is to really justify every step. 

I reached $F'=f$ for $x\neq 1$  by checking what $F$ is on each interval by applying the second fundamental theorem of calculus.

In summary, this is an exercise in learning about the theorems, that's why I tend to put in all the steps

Comment: $f$ is continuous except at $x=1$ so $F'$ exists everywhere except perhaps at $x=1$ where we showed it does not. On the other hand, since you're checking differentiability, I guess it's easy just to use the definition.